# word vba Select specific page of specific Section

Tags: vba, select, ms-word

I use **p1s11,s9,s12** in blow code to print page 1 of section 11 and section 9 (entirely) and section 12 (entirely)

```
Application.PrintOut OutputFileName:=FinalNamePath,
Range:=wdPrintRangeOfPages, Item:=wdPrintDocumentWithMarkup,
Copies:=1, Pages:"p1s11,s9,s12", PageType:=wdPrintAllPages,
Collate:=True, Background:=True,
PrintToFile:=False,PrintZoomColumn:=0, PrintZoomRow:=0,
PrintZoomPaperWidth:=0,PrintZoomPaperHeight:=0
```

now I want to select page 1 of section 11 **and** section 9 **and** section 12

I searched a lot and I get the below for single selection

```
ActiveDocument.Sections(11).Range.Select
```

but it selects the entire section

also, I found the below for multible selection

```
With ActiveDocument
.Range(.Sections(2).Range.Start, .Sections(5).Range.End).Select
Selection.Copy
End With
```

but it selects sequential sections only (entirely)

I want to select page 1 of section 11 **and** section 9 (entirely) **and** section 12 (entirely)

in not sequential sections

how to do this

Comment: It is not possible to select non-consecutive parts of the document.

Comment: Word will not *select* these non-contiguous spots, AFAIK. You might try adding them to the spike, but I am unsure how that would be done or would work.

Comment: Cross-posted at: https://www.excelforum.com/word-programming-vba-macros/1378138-word-vba-select-specific-page-of-specific-section.html. 
For cross-posting etiquette, please read: http://www.excelguru.ca/content.php?184

Comment: ok , i don't want non-contiguous , how to select page 1 of section 11 ??

Comment: Why do you need to `Select` the page? Most things can be done in VBA without selecting anything.